# distinguish file and directory in PHP

Tags: php, file, directory

my problem is a php page that extracts the contents of a directory.
As you can see in the snippet below, the path is passed via GET.
The first time I call the page reads everything correctly, but if you just read the folder contains a sub-directory, it is recognized as a file.
Do you have any advice or solution? 
thanks

```
 <?php
     $path = $_GET['dir'];
     function createDir($path) {
         if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
             echo "<ul>";
             while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                 if (is_dir($path . $file) && $file != '.' && $file != '..')
                     printSubDir($file, $path, $queue);
                 else if ($file != '.' && $file != '..')
                     $queue[] = $file;
             }

             printQueue($queue, $path);
             echo "</ul>";
         }
     }

     function printQueue($queue, $path) {
         foreach ($queue as $file) {
             printFile($file, $path);
         }
     }

     function printFile($file, $path) {
         echo "<li>";
            // print a file
         echo "</li>";
     }

     function printSubDir($dir, $path) {
         echo "<li>";
            // print a directory
         echo "</li>";
     }

     createDir($path);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use the [DirectoryIterator](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php) to easily achieve this:

```
$oIterator = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
foreach ($oIterator as $oFileInfo) {

    // Either . or ..
    if ($oFileinfo->isDot()) {

    }

    // A directory
    if ($oFileInfo->isDir()) {

    }
}
```

Comment: The solution works well, but isDot don't work. i try with if (($oFileinfo!=".") && ($oFileinfo!="..")) but the "." and ".." directories are also extracted.. any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is_dir()` or `is_file()` to check this and than use recursive functions to read those as well. If it's just to mark is as a directory you can just use the check.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php